# How can I install modules using the FTP method?

Tags: updating

I got a error when trying to install modules. What should I set up for the FTP? I just learned Drupal. Who knows what happen? I am using Drupal 7.7.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As kalabro said:

Make sure the folder /sites/default is OWNED by the user that executes the drupal scripts.

On most Ubuntu installations, this is the user Apache user www-data.

```
chown www-data sites/default
```

Comment: Under macOS `chown _www sites/default` and `chown _www  modules`.

Answer (score 4):

Updating modules using that method works only if the server running Drupal also runs a FTP server; in that case, you need to enter the username and the password to connect to the FTP server. The server is normally "localhost" as both the web server and the FTP server are running from the same IP; if that is not the case, then you should change "localhost" with the name of the server (e.g. ftp.example.com).

If you are running Drupal on your local computer, as when you use it as testing site, then if you don't have a FTP server on your computer, you cannot use that way to update modules; in that case, you just copy the files on your computer, after you download the archives containing the updated versions.

Comment: I have a vsftpd already installed on my local machine and is running. Do I need to create an additional FTP account which its root directory is same as the Drupal's Web server directory?

Comment: That is how the FTP server on my web server is configured. Once you created the account, you use the login credentials in the form you shown in the screenshot.

Comment: No luck. I have an FTP account pointing to my web server root directory. But it is still failed after I enter the credential.

Comment: Did you try copying any file using an FTP client, and verified the data for the login are correct?

Comment: [Check this](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-7#comment-4844050), please. Quote: `To avoid this, make sure the folder /sites/default is OWNED by the user that executes the drupal scripts. On most Ubuntu installations, this is the user apache user: www-data.`

Comment: you can also use drush to install modules: `drush dl module_name; drush en module_name -y`

Answer (score 2):

Do not make www-data own /sites/default or any other folder except for /sites//files or /files once the site is live. The "install module" feature within drupal should only be used during site development, when the site is not live. The server should not be able to write to /sites/all or /sites/default or any other folder (except files) as this is a security risk.
Again, it may seem convenient to do it that way, but having the server write to any folder except files is a very bad plan. You may be pwned.

Answer (score 1):

I have run  the following command and it workes wonder!!

```
sudo chown -R www-data sites/default
```

Answer (score -1):

In case, if you've access to `/sites/all/modules` directory then you can also prefer directly uploading the `module-name.tar.gz`:

- extract the zip  copy the directory to `/sites/all/modules/`
- In web-site, navigate through `admin-bar -> modules`
- check the module in the list
- Save configuration

This should install the new module.